# Setting vector X to nearest value of vector Y among other 2 vectors

Tags: r

Dataframe is

```
**Y    Y1    Y2     

58   65    59     
60   61    61.4   
56   52    78     
64   78    80**
```

And My expected output should be as given below, where X should reference Y and choose value among Y1,Y2 which-soever is nearer.
X is my expected new output column and Y is the reference one.

```
Y    Y1    Y2     X

58   65    59     59
60   61    61.4   61
56   52    78     52
64   78    80     78
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `ifelse()` to compare the difference between the two vector values and the initial values, and choose the lower:

```
df <- data.frame(Y = c(58,60,56,64),
                 Y1 = c(65,61,52,78),
                 Y2 = c(59,61.4,78,80))

df$X <- with(df, ifelse(abs(Y1-Y) < abs(Y2-Y), Y1, Y2))

   Y Y1   Y2  X
1 58 65 59.0 59
2 60 61 61.4 61
3 56 52 78.0 52
4 64 78 80.0 78
```

---

Edit: As @RuiBarradas pointed out, the comparison should probably be done on absolute values. I've changed the `ifelse()` condition to account for this.

Comment: Shouldn't that be comparisons between *absolute* values? For instance, in row 3 if `Y2 == 57` then `Y1 - Y` is negative and less than `Y2 - Y` though `Y2` is closer.

Comment: Solid point. I'll edit in a version with comparison of absolutes.

Comment: Thanks LAP and Rui